# Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, discrete-data

Let $(X_1,Y_1), . . . , (X_n,Y_n)$ be a random sample from the discrete distribution with joint probability mass function
$$ f_{X,Y} (x,y) = \frac{\theta}4 , \space   (x,y) = (0,0)\space or \space(1,1)$$
                $$ = \frac{2 - \theta}4, \space \space (x,y) = (0,1)\space or \space(1,0),$$

with $0 \le \theta \le 2$.

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: Is this homework/self-study? Add the tag and your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: You've posted quite a few routine bookwork questions. Please use the self-study tag for such questions, and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see what to include when you ask one.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X,Y) = (X_{1},Y_{1}), \ldots, (X_{n},Y_{n})$.

The likelihood of your sample is:

$$
 P((X,Y)|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{X_{i},Y_{i}}\frac{\theta}{4} + (1-\delta_{X_{i},Y_{i}})\frac{2-\theta}{4}) 
$$

$\delta_{X_{i},Y_{i}} = 1$ if $X_{i} = Y_{i}$ and $= 0$ otherwise.

If $k$ is the number of times $X_{i} = Y_{i}$ in your sample, so:

$$
 P((X,Y)|\theta) = (\frac{\theta}{4})^{k}(\frac{2-\theta}{4})^{n-k}
$$

Maximize that for $\theta$ and you will find that the best estimator for $\theta$ is $\frac{2k}{n}$.

Comment: You handed the home work solution

Comment: Thanks, but a little heads-up would have sufficed, since I was thinking along the same line.

Comment: Great answer.  I don't get how you're supposed to answer these type of questions effectively without providing almost the full solution.  If you don't want an almost complete solution then be VERY specific with the question.